# How do I configure Visual Studio to include my web application's name in the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

When debugging locally in the browser, the URL is in this format:

```
http://localhost:63431/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]
```

On the server, the URL is in this format:

```
http://www.example.com/[ApplicationName]/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]
```

Because of the exclusion of the [ApplicationName] locally, however, all of my JavaScript Ajax URLs in my stand-alone JavaScript break when on the server.

How do I make Visual Studio add [ApplicationName] to the URL when debugging, so that my local environment matches the server environment?

---

**Edit:**

As requested, here is how I generate my Ajax URLS:

```
var options = {
                url: $form.attr("action"),
                type: $form.attr("method"),
                data: data,
                dataType: "html"
            };
```

For some reason, the server (IIS) expects these URLS to be in this format:

```
/[ApplicationName]/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]
```

But locally, this format works (this is the format generated by the Ajax code above):

```
/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]
```

Comment: Can you use relative links in your ajax calls?

Comment: Its the way your generating your ajax url's that is wrong (show how your generating them)

Comment: How are your generating the the `action` attribute in the form. If you using `Html.BeginForm()` (or manually generating the html with `Url.Action()` it will be fine

Comment: I'm using HTML.BeginForm() to craft the form and thus the action.  Interestingly enough, HTML.BeginForm appears to have crafted the URLs correctly, including the app's name when it's on the server and not including it when debugging locally.  Odd- time for some more research.  I will post again when I know more (a few minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Visual studio development server in your local machine. You can have the required URL structure if you use IIS instead.

Either

1. Copy the application folder into wwwroot folder (typically in the path c:\inetpub), open inetmgr, right click your folder listed under default website, and select convert as application. You will see the url in the required format.

Or

2. Create a virtual directory in the application name under default website in IIS pointing to your application folder.

Hope this will help.